# Write an object-oriented program that produces one example from each signature combination available to that language

Tags: code-golf

Write an object-oriented program that, when ran, outputs one complete example from each reserved-word-vise unique signature combination available to that language. Reserved words for primitive types are excluded. Each example should start from a new line.

This implies that for all signatures any changes in parameters, return types or in their counts do not contribute towards the goal.

The resulting output for Java could be something like this:

```
private int a;
protected int a;
public int a;
private static int a;
protected static int a;
public static int a;
private static final int a;
protected static final int a;
...
private void a(){};
protected void a(){};
...
private abstract void a();
protected abstract void a();
...
```

Comment: Does the solution itself have to be OOP, or the output?

Comment: only for primitive type or for classes too? this would be extremly large, because there are thousands of classes...

Comment: @Doorknob Yes the solution must be an object-oriented program that prints the combinations for the same language

Comment: @PhilippSander as stated, changing types do not count as they are just different instances for the same signature combination.

Comment: Who determines whether our code is object oriented? I don't think that a program is necessarily object oriented just because it was written in a particular language.

Comment: @John it is true that many languages are multi-paradigm. I'm hopeful that for solutions not meeting the general definitions of OOP, they are pointed out by the community and accordingly met.

Comment: It's clear that what you mean by *signature* isn't what e.g. the Java Language Specification means by *signature* (*Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types*), but since you haven't specified what you do mean this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I don't think the edit helps. I can tell that you're really asking about something to do with possible partial expansions of declaration-related non-tokens of the language grammar, but you don't give any definitions, and all I can infer from the incomplete example is that you seem to be avoiding some illegal combinations but not all of them; and that you want to at minimum include field and either method or constructor declarations (but what about classes, interfaces, annotations, properties, namespaces, ...? And can I claim to use an earlier version of a language to reduce the cases?)